If an app implemented a novel feature but has since gone out of business, can this be prior art?
Suppose that a novel feature that was implemented by an app that is now out of business is claimed in a patent application with a filing date after the app has gone out of business.
Being out of business means that the app is no longer operational.
There is no documentation regarding the feature of this app.
If the app's developer were to try to invalid the patent, what means can they use to achieve this given that their app is no longer operational? How would they be able to prove that the claimed feature had already been invented?

Anything publicly disclosed prior to the patent application filing date is prior art. This doesn’t mean the examiner will find it. The process to invalidate would depend on what stage the application/patent is at and the country you’re filing in. There are other questions and answers already on this site regarding invalidating patents so please search those.
